# Updating a deleted App

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

a client of mine has accidentally deleted his App from itunesconnect. Which stil has a lot of users and we want to update this app. Which unfortunately is not possible because he deleted it and didn't put it on status "Removed from sale", not so smart.

But is there still a way to resubmit this app with the same bundle id to update the app which the existing users already have installed? Or is this impossible? Or is there no way to reach those users which have the app already installed.

Does someone know how the updating system in iOS works? Does the app has to use the same specific bundle id and SKU? Or is it possible to update the app with a different developer account which uses the same bundle id and name of the app because it was deleted by a different developer.

Or is this impossible to do and is the only option left to republish the app under a different name. And try to force the existing users to re-download the updated version of the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you delete your app, you can't restore it. The SKU or app name can't be reused in the same organization.
See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html) & [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW35).

[image]